# response[i] is undefined in forloop inside ajax success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, response

**Error**

```
TypeError: response[i] is undefined


    ...box' class='selectedSubjects' name='selectedSubjects' />
</td><td class='selected...
```

**Array**

```
[{"S_Code":"BCS-CER-IS","S_Name":"Information Systems.","C_Code":"BCS-CER","S_Status":"Active"},
{"S_Code":"BCS-CER-SD","S_Name":"Software Development.","C_Code":"BCS-CER","S_Status":"Active"},
{"S_Code":"BCS-CER-TEC","S_Name":"Computer & Network Technology","C_Code":"BCS-CER","S_Status":"Active"}]
```

**AJAX success Call back**

```
success: function (response) {
    var size = response.filter(function (value) {
        return value !== undefined
    }).length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        $("#subjectsTable tr:last").after("<tr class='success' data-index=" + (i + 1) + "><td><input type='checkbox' class='selectedSubjects' name='selectedSubjects' /></td><td class='selectedSCode'>" + response[i].S_Code + "</td><td class='selectedSName'>" + response[i].S_Name + "</td></tr>");

    }
}
```

Why this response[i] is undefined ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be `i < size` as array index is from `0` to `length-1`

```
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    $("#subjectsTable tr:last").after("<tr class='success' data-index=" + (i + 1) + "><td><input type='checkbox' class='selectedSubjects' name='selectedSubjects' /></td><td class='selectedSCode'>" + response[i].S_Code + "</td><td class='selectedSName'>" + response[i].S_Name + "</td></tr>");

}
```

so when `i == size` the value of `response[i]` will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work

```
for (var i = 0; i <= (size - 1); i++) {
        $("#subjectsTable tr:last").after("<tr class='success' data-index=" + (i + 1) + "><td><input type='checkbox' class='selectedSubjects' name='selectedSubjects' /></td><td class='selectedSCode'>" + response[i].S_Code + "</td><td class='selectedSName'>" + response[i].S_Name + "</td></tr>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
success: function (response) {
    var filtered = response.filter(function (value) {
        return value !== undefined
    });
    var size = filtered.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        $("#subjectsTable tr:last").after("<tr class='success' data-index=" + (i + 1) + "><td><input type='checkbox' class='selectedSubjects' name='selectedSubjects' /></td><td class='selectedSCode'>" + filtered[i].S_Code + "</td><td class='selectedSName'>" + filtered[i].S_Name + "</td></tr>");

    }
}
```

If you taking size of only filtered ones then use filtered array to avoid null or undefined values. Also i < size .